# Why using call to overwrite `this` in a parent component callback does not work?

Tags: reactjs

Assuming the `Parent` component is rendered somewhere and the `a` element in its child is clicked, the following code will result in logging: `Parent {props: ...} 'Hello from child'` instead of what I'd expect, i.e.: `Child {props: ...] 'Hello from child'`.

Isn't using `call` supposed to overwrite the `this` reference in the callback? What am I missing?

```js
class Parent extends Component {
 constructor() { /* ... */ }
 myCallback(text) { console.log(this, text); }

 render() {
   return (
     <Child callbacks={{cb1: this.myCallback.bind(this)}} />
   );
 }
}

class Child extends Component {
 constructor() { /* ... */ }
 onClick(e) {
   // ...
   this.props.callbacks.cb1.call(this, 'Hello from child');
 }

 render() {
   return (
     <a href='#' onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}>Link</a>
   );
 }
}
```

Comment: There's quite a few strange things here. Why are you rebinding `this` at all? Why not just have the code that Child needs to trigger *in Child*? Possibly with a parent fallthrough like `handle() { console.log(...); if (this.props.writeText) { this.props.writeText(...); }}`? Also, why not pass the functions you need with sensible propnames? Don't hide handlers in an object, write clear code and use well-named properties. Also, `<a>` i HTML5 is exclusively for navigation. If you need a button, instead of navigating, use a `<button>` and style it to look like whatever you need it to look like.

Comment: You're right about this being an anti-pattern, I'm just using this code to understand the React flow, it's not production code.

Comment: then stop, and instead run through (not read, actually just write this yourself, too) the code on http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html - this attempt is going to cement bad patterns into your mind because you're exploring them *while learning React*. Learn React first, the right way.

Comment: Followup: as a matter of principle, isn't there something to be said for keeping callbacks that deal with state management in a container component, instead of spreading state management across different child components? (I know there are are better ways of doing this with flux)

Comment: state is a component's internal responsibility, one component should never be responsible for another component's state - the most it can do is either, as parent, give a child new props, or, as child, send a signal to the parent through a function dedicated to the purpose passed down by the parent as a property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Isn't using `call` supposed to overwrite the `this` reference in the callback? What am I missing?

The `this` value of a bound function (`this.myCallback.bind(this)`) cannot be changed, no matter how the function is called.

Comment: You're right. Here's the paragraph in the documentation: `The bind() function creates a new function (a bound function) with the same function body (internal call property in ECMAScript 5 terms) as the function it is being called on (the bound function's target function) with the this value bound to the first argument of bind(), *which cannot be overridden*.`